# Integration, computation of integral in $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am student in first year in economics. I don't have enough knowledge on integration.

I want to compute this integral:

\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} (\ln(p))(\ln(1-p)) dp
\end{equation*}

It will be great if you can detail the proof.

Comment: It seems that there is no [closed expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D+ln%28p%29+ln%281-p%29+dp)... but I was wrong. :(

Answer (score 7):

By the substitution $p = e^{-u}$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \log p \log(1-p) \, dp
&= - \int_{0}^{\infty} u e^{-u} \log(1-e^{-u}) \, du.
\end{align*}

Then by the Taylor expansion of the logarithm,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \log p \log(1-p) \, dp
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} u e^{-u} \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-nu}}{n} \right\} \, du \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} u e^{-(n+1)u} \, du \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)^{2}} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} \right) \\
&= 2 - \zeta(2)
 = 2-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6} \\
&\approx 0.355065933151773563527584833354\cdots.
\end{align*}

Or we can just make use of the beta function

$$ \beta(z, w) = \frac{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)}{\Gamma(z+w)} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{z-1}(1-x)^{w-1} \, dx $$

to obtain

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \log p \log(1-p) \, dp
&= \frac{\partial^{2} \beta}{\partial z \partial w}(1, 1) \\
&= \beta(1, 1) \left\{ \left( \psi^{(0)}(1)-\psi ^{(0)}(2) \right)^{2} - \psi^{(1)}(2) \right\} \\
&= 1 \cdot \{ (-1)^{2} - (\zeta(2) - 1) \} \\
&= 2 - \zeta(2).
\end{align*}

Comment: Taylor series directly =)
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^1 \log(1-z)\log z & = \int_0^1 \log z \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n} \right) dz \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 z^n \cdot \log z dz \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left\{ \left[ \frac{z^{n+1}\log z}{z+1} \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{z^n}{n+1} dz \right\} \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \\ & = \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) - \left( -\frac{1}{(0+1)^2} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right) \\
    & = 1 + 1 - \zeta(2) = 2 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: sos440, can you help me for the following equation : $k\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$:
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1} \left[\ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\right]^{k}p^{2}dp
,\quad
J=\int_{0}^{1} \left[\ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\right]^{k}pdp 
,\quad K=\int_{0}^{1} \left[\ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\right]^{k}dp.
$$ I am not really familiar with the beta function